# How to mangle functions with Uglify based on previous mangling

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a js library that must be obfuscated for release. However, the library supports plugins which may be written by users. The plug-ins must also be obfuscated, but in exactly the same way so that they work with the library.

In other words:
MyLibrary.js, which contains

```
class1.function1()
```

gets changed to

```
a.b()
```

At a later time a user writes a plugin that calls the function

```
plugin(function(){
...
   class1.function1()
...
})
```

I must be able to pass the information of the map 'class1' => 'a' and 'funciton1' => 'b' to the mangle option of Uglify to change the new code to

```
plugin(function(){
...
   a.b()
...
})
```

Is this at all possible? The key here, I suspect, is for Uglify to output the obfuscation map at the end of the operation so that it can be used again later.

Note: It is, of course, possible not to obfuscate some functions, but the users that write the plugins will have access to privileged documentation that is not publicly available, so their code must also be obfuscated.

**Edit:**
A further clarification: The project loads plugins at run-time with ajax (as needed), as well as it allows for json encoding of method calls, so that actions or events can be encoded with the dom elements. Thus, whatever method may be suggested, it must involve an intermediary symbol translation map that is enforced at later times.

Comment: Public API obfuscation? Really?

Comment: This is more like third-party API obfuscation, which i think is an interesting concept in its own right.

Comment: As far as I know, rollup.js is generating flat output, maybe it will be more obfuscatable

Comment: rollup.js is a useful tool. I will think about using it more generally. But, it assumes that all the code is generated together. The problem I have is how to do consistent obfuscation across builds. I made an edit to clarify.